# where clause in select statement - datetime issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to put a where clause in my select statement based on the year and month of a timestamp field in my db

I have a month and a year dropdownlist which give me the following string 01/2012

The date format in my db is "2012-01-01 00:00:00" but when I select an individual date and put it in a message box it converts to "01/01/2012"

I've altered my select statement below to reflect the converted date. However Im still not given the correct details. Any ideas? Is there a particular format that I need to use when dealing with a timestamp field? Can I even use the "Right" function in a select statement?

```
Dim newRecordDate As String = val1 & "/" & ComboBox2.SelectedValue 
Dim sql2 As String = "Select CatA, CatB, CatC,  Cost, Currency, MarketingCode, Comment, RecordDate from vw_tblP_Usage_Details where puid = '" & puid & "' right(RecordDate, 7) = '" & newRecordDate & "'"
```

Comment: With the following select statement I get the error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." `Dim sql As String = "Select CatA, CatB, CatC, Cost, Currency, MarketingCode, Comment, RecordDate from vw_tblP_Usage_Details where puid = '" & uid & "' and CONVERT(DATETIME, RecordDate, 102) = '" & newRecordDate & "'".`

Comment: What database server are you using? sqlserver? mysql? ...

Comment: I guess you need to check if you "record date" is not null and has the proper date format. Do you do that?

Comment: No its definitely not null, I can see it in my view...

Comment: How do you fill this column in the first place, how do you make sure the string format is the proper format for conversion?

Answer (score 7):

I say use parameters and the `SqlParameter` class to pass parameter values to sql server from .NET client instead of using concatenation and string formatting. It makes life easier.

Something Like This:

```
Dim myDate As Date = DateTime.Now
Dim sql As String = "Select * from SomeTable where MyDate = @some_param"

Using Command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@some_param", myDate)

    Using reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()

        'other code here
    End Using
End Using
```